# Delphi - Store WideStrings inside a program

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7, widestring

In the past I used INI-Files to store unicode text, but now I need to store unicode text in the executable. How can I achieve this?

I want to store these letters:

```
āčēūīšķļņž
```

Comment: You do know that my approach below is to be written in a *.PAS (or *.DPR) file, not in a *.DFM file?

Comment: Working with Unicode characters in Delphi 7 is extremely boring. It would be a really, really good idea to upgrade to Delphi 2009+. Alternatively, you can switch to Free Pascal/Lazarus, which is free.

Comment: I can't get Delphi 2009+ because Im 14 yrs old and dont have any money, C'mon people.

Comment: Lazarus is the IDE (with a GUI) for the Free Pascal compiler.

Comment: FreePascal/Lazarus don't cost any money. Probably still better than Delphi 7.

Comment: @Robrok: The ' before ) at the end of the red line shouldn't be there.

Comment: If you have switched to FP/Lazarus and are having issues there, I think you should ask a new Q.

Comment: @Robrok: The latter problem can probably be solved by telling Lazarus to save your source files as Unicode or UTF-8 files. Try the options dialog, or the editor right-click menu.

Comment: @Robrok - ok, so you are back in Delphi now. Once again, the answer what Andreas provided is right. You are probably trying to display your Unicode constant in a certain non Unicode component or function. Note that Delphi 7 has no built-in component supporting Unicode and most of the functions are also ANSI (non Unicode). And that the source files are saved also as ANSI so you can't save the chars like `āčēūīšķļņž` directly in your source file, you need to use their ordinal values.

Comment: I get it a long time ago, thanks people for respond!

Comment: Your question *right now* seems like a simple one. What difficulty are you having storing Unicode text in your program?

Comment: The code you've added doesn't really store Unicode text. Maybe that's your problem. You're storing Ansi text because that's what TIniFile does; it doesn't store Unicode text in INI files. For that, you'd need a Unicode version of Delphi.

Comment: @LittleHelper "*I can't get Delphi 2009+ because Im 14 yrs old and dont have any money*" - the [Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter) of Delphi is free (at least until your revenue from your software reaches $5000).

Comment: @RobKennedy "*You're storing Ansi text because that's what TIniFile does; it doesn't store Unicode text in INI files. For that, you'd need a Unicode version of Delphi*" - or, just skip using `TIniFile` and use the Unicode version of the `(Get|Write)PrivateProfile...()` Wi32 API functions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you definitely need to use Delphi 7 there are some variants:

1. Store strings in resources linked to executable file.
2. Store strings in big memo or same thing, located on global data module or any other visual or non-visual component and access it by index. It's possible because strings in Delphi resources stored in XML-encoded form. E.g. your symbols example `āčēūīšķļņž` will be stored as `&#257;&#269;&#275;&#363;&#299;&#353;&#311;&#316;&#326;&#382;`
3. Store XML-encoded or Base64-encoded strings in string constants inside your code.

For string conversion you can use EncdDecd.pas , xdom.pas or some functions of System.pas like UTF8Encode/UTF8Decode.

To display and edit Unicode strings in Delphi forms you can use special set of Unicode controls like [TNT Unicode Controls](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index?DokuWiki=babsgjsj7a3eh0ti5qiuk62033) or subclass original Delphi controls and do some other workarounds by yourself, like described in this excerpt from comments in TntControls.pas (part of TNT Unicode Controls):

> Windows NT provides support for native Unicode windows.  To add
>   Unicode support to a
>       TWinControl descendant, override CreateWindowHandle() and call
>   CreateUnicodeHandle().
>
> One major reason this works is because the VCL only uses the ANSI
>   version of
>       SendMessage() -- SendMessageA().  If you call SendMessageA() on a
>   UNICODE
>       window, Windows deals with the ANSI/UNICODE conversion
>   automatically.  So
>       for example, if the VCL sends WM_SETTEXT to a window using
>   SendMessageA,
>       Windows actually *expects* a PAnsiChar even if the target window
>   is a UNICODE
>       window.  So caling SendMessageA with PChars causes no problems.
>
> A problem in the VCL has to do with the TControl.Perform() method.
>   Perform()
>       calls the window procedure directly and assumes an ANSI window. 
>   This is a
>       problem if, for example, the VCL calls Perform(WM_SETTEXT, ...)
>   passing in a
>       PAnsiChar which eventually gets passed downto DefWindowProcW()
>   which expects a PWideChar.
>
> This is the reason for SubClassUnicodeControl().  This procedure
>   will subclass the
>       Windows WndProc, and the TWinControl.WindowProc pointer.  It will
>   determine if the
>       message came from Windows or if the WindowProc was called
>   directly.  It will then
>       call SendMessageA() for Windows to perform proper conversion on
>   certain text messages.
>
> Another problem has to do with TWinControl.DoKeyPress().  It is
>   called from the WM_CHAR
>       message.  It casts the WideChar to an AnsiChar, and sends the
>   resulting character to
>       DefWindowProc.  In order to avoid this, the DefWindowProc is
>   subclassed as well.  WindowProc
>       will make a WM_CHAR message safe for ANSI handling code by
>   converting the char code to
>       #FF before passing it on.  It stores the original WideChar in the
>   .Unused field of TWMChar.
>       The code #FF is converted back to the WideChar before passing onto
>   DefWindowProc.

Comment: Yes i am using TNT controls to display unicode text instead of MessageBoxW(Handle, PWideChar(MyString), 'Caption', 0);

Comment: @Robrok - about how to store Unicode INI files. My answer was wrong. At least in D2007 I haven't found the overriden constructor with TEncoding. I'll try to update it.

Comment: `TEncoding` was added in D2009

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the Unicode INI files then you might try the following code. The files are saved in [UTF8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Also you might take a look at [this Unicode library](http://fundementals.sourceforge.net/unicode.html) where you can find a lot of helper functions.

```
uses IniFiles;

function WideStringToUTF8(const Value: WideString): AnsiString;
var
  BufferLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  if Value <> '' then
  begin
    BufferLen := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(Value), -1, nil, 0, nil, nil);
    SetLength(Result, BufferLen - 1);
    if BufferLen > 1 then
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(Value), -1, PAnsiChar(Result), BufferLen - 1, nil, nil);
  end;
end;

function UTF8ToWideString(const Value: AnsiString): WideString;
var
  BufferLen: integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  if Value <> '' then
  begin
    BufferLen := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(Value), -1, nil, 0);
    SetLength(Result, BufferLen - 1);
    if BufferLen > 1 then
      MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(Value), -1, PWideChar(Result), BufferLen - 1);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
const
  UnicodeValue = WideString(#$0101#$010D#$0113#$016B#$012B#$0161);
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('C:\test.ini');

  try
    IniFile.WriteString('Section', 'Key', WideStringToUTF8(UnicodeValue));
    IniFile.UpdateFile;
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  UnicodeValue: WideString;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('C:\test.ini');

  try
    UnicodeValue := UTF8ToWideString(IniFile.ReadString('Section', 'Key', 'Default'));
    MessageBoxW(Handle, PWideChar(UnicodeValue), 'Caption', 0);
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]
with Delphi 2007 on 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
const MyString = WideString('Teksts latvie'#$0161'u valod'#$0101);
```

Comment: @Robrok: Since I cannot ready your mind, I don't know what is wrong with it. (It *does* work in the sense that the string *is* stored as a wide string in memory...) Maybe you are trying to store Unicode characters in an ANSI source file? Try `WideString('Teksts latvie'#$0161'u valod'#$0101')`. (You can obtain the character codes in many ways -- using `charmap`, a decent text editor (like [Rejbrand Text Editor](http://english.rejbrand.se/rteditor/)), or -- easiest -- using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%C5%A1).)

Comment: I am using Delphi-7 and if i paste this: const MyString : WideString='āčēūīšķļņž' to Delphi unit it transforms to this: const MyString : WideString=('a-c(e-u-i-s(k,l,n,z(');

Comment: @Robrok: Andreas is trying to help. It doesn't make that easy if you act like that. I don't remember if Delphi 7 supports it, but try to set the source file to Unicode or UTF8, if possible.

Comment: How you are showing that string ? Have you tried e.g. `MessageBoxW(Handle, PWideChar(MyString), 'Caption', 0);` ? Don't forget you have no Unicode components in Delphi 7. And most of the functions like ShowMessage won't be Unicode too. You need to use only Unicode compatible things

Comment: Yes i use this boring thing ^^^

Comment: @Robrok - anyway that boring `W` at the end of the `MessageBoxW` means `Widestring`. There is also the `MessageBoxA` what is the `ANSI` version of the same function and the `MessageBox` which in your Delphi 7 refers to the `MessageBoxA` because your Delphi are ANSI, not Unicode. If you would have D2009+, then the `MessageBox` would refer to the `MessageBoxW`, because D2009+ are Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the idea is to find a non-visual component, which can store text and store your text there.  Prefer that such component can also provide you an editor to edit the text in design time.

There is a component call `FormResource` which can do this.  I use `TUniScript`.  I believe there are other similar components.  However, I did not find a usable component from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The approach `Widestring(#$65E5#$672C)` does not work, because Delphi 7 just doesn't expect  more than one byte for the `#`, so the outcome is by far not what you expect when going above 255 or $FF.

Another approach `WideChar($65E5)+ WideChar($672C)` can be used to store single Unicode codepoints in your source code when knowing that you need to have a `Widestring` at the start of the assignment (which can also be an empty literal) so the compiler understands which datatype you want:

```
const
  // Compiler error "Imcompatible types"
  WONT_COMPILE: WideChar($65E5)+ WideChar($672C);

  // 日本
  NIPPON: Widestring('')+ WideChar($65E5)+ WideChar($672C);
```

Looks cumbersome, but surely has your UTF-16 texts in Delphi 7.

Alternatively, store your constants in UTF-8, which is ASCII safe - that way you can use `#` easily. One advantage is, that it's a lot less cumbersome to write in your source code. One disadvantage is, that you can never use the constant directly, but have to convert it to UTF-16 first:

```
const
  // UTF-8 of the two graphemes 日 and 本, needing 3 bytes each
  NIPPON: #$E6#$97#$A5#$E6#$9C#$AC;
var
  sUtf16: Widestring;
begin
  // Internally these are 2 WORDs: $65E5 and $672C
  sUtf16:= UTF8ToWideString( NIPPON );
```